# How to return a value from a function when it is used as a command function? How to close a user interface when a button is pressed?

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter

I'm pretty new in python. I developed a simple GUI with tkinter for a file selection. When a button is pressed an open file dialog is activated and user can select a file from a folder. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


# %% create a command associated to the window button
def open_file():
    initialDir = '/';
    fileTypes = (('Text files', '*.txt'), ('Csv files', '*.csv'), ('All files', '*.*'));
    Title = 'Choose a file';
    filename = str(fd.askopenfile(title=Title, filetypes=fileTypes));
        
    
# %% create a GUI
window = tk.Tk();
window.title('Tkinter GUI Open File Dialog');
window.resizable(False, False);
window.geometry('300x150');


# %% open file button
open_button = ttk.Button(window, text='Open a File',command=open_file);
open_button.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='w', padx=10, pady=10)


# %% run window - automatic closing after 10 seconds
window.after(10000,lambda:window.destroy())
window.mainloop();
```

I would like to get the filename of the selected file.
Moreover, I would like to close the gui when the button is pressed and the filename becomes known.
Thank you all!

Comment: you have to assing value to `globa` variable `vecause now `filename` is local variable. And later you can run `window.destroy()` to close GUI. BTW: user may click `Cancel` and then `askopenfile` will give `None` so better check it and keep value only if there is no `None`

Comment: shorter `window.after( 10000, window.destroy )` - without `lambda` and without `()`

Comment: in python you don't need `;` at the end of line

Comment: thank you! i moved the window.destroy() command after the filename definition. It works fine!

`filename = str(fd.askopenfile(title=Title, filetypes=fileTypes));
    window.destroy()`

i would like to use the code, namely _uigetfile_, in such a way:

`filename= uigetfile()`

Comment: you could put all code inside function but it may have again problem with local/global variables and you may need to use `global` in `uigetfile` and in all function inside `uigetfile`

Comment: you could create main window, hide it and run directly `askopenfilename` without button.

Comment: Instead of adding the word "Solved" to the title of your question you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you found most helpful by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. This will let the system know this question is answered in a way that the word "Solved" in the title does not.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry! Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment you assign it to local variable `filename` but if you add  `global filename` inside function then it will assign to global variable.

It may be good to assign to global variable some default value at start - so it will exists even if you don't select file.

If you want only filename (instead of reference to opened file) then use `askopenfilename` instead of `askopenfile`

And if you click `Cancel` then `askopenfilename` should give `None` and it could be better to keep it as `None` instead of convert to string. And later you should check if `filename` is `None` to run code only if you really selected filename.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

filename = None # default value in global variable

# %% create a command associated to the window button
def open_file():
    global filename  # inform function to use global variable instead of local one
    
    initialDir = '/'
    fileTypes = (('Text files', '*.txt'), ('Csv files', '*.csv'), ('All files', '*.*'))
    Title = 'Choose a file'
    
    # use askopenfilename instead of askopenfile to get only name
    
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(title=Title, filetypes=fileTypes)
        
    # destroy GUI
    window.destroy()
    
# %% create a GUI
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Tkinter GUI Open File Dialog')
window.resizable(False, False)
window.geometry('300x150')

# %% open file button
open_button = ttk.Button(window, text='Open a File',command=open_file)
open_button.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='w', padx=10, pady=10)

# %% run window - automatic closing after 10 seconds
window.after(10000, window.destroy)
window.mainloop()

if filename:  # check if filename was really selected
    print('selected:', filename)
else:
    print("you didn't select filename")
```

---

If you want to keep all in function then it may need to use `global` in all functions

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

def get_filename():
    global filename
    
    filename = None # default value in global variable
    
    # %% create a command associated to the window button
    def open_file():
        global filename  # inform function to use global variable instead of local one
        
        initialDir = '/'
        fileTypes = (('Text files', '*.txt'), ('Csv files', '*.csv'), ('All files', '*.*'))
        Title = 'Choose a file'
        
        # use askopenfilename instead of askopenfile to get only name
        
        filename = fd.askopenfilename(title=Title, filetypes=fileTypes)
            
        window.destroy()
        
    # %% create a GUI
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title('Tkinter GUI Open File Dialog')
    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.geometry('300x150')
    
    # %% open file button
    open_button = ttk.Button(window, text='Open a File',command=open_file)
    open_button.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='w', padx=10, pady=10)
    
    # %% run window - automatic closing after 10 seconds
    window.after(10000, window.destroy)
    window.mainloop()
    
    return filename

# --- main ---

filename = get_filename()

if filename:  # check if filename was really selected
    print('selected:', filename)
else:
    print("you didn't select filename")
```

---

Popular method is also to create main window, hide it and directly run `askopenfilename` without button

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

def get_filename():
    global filename
    
    filename = None # default value in global variable
    
    # %% create a command associated to the window button
    def open_file():
        global filename  # inform function to use global variable instead of local one
        
        initialDir = '/'
        fileTypes = (('Text files', '*.txt'), ('Csv files', '*.csv'), ('All files', '*.*'))
        Title = 'Choose a file'
        
        # use askopenfilename instead of askopenfile to get only name
        
        filename = fd.askopenfilename(title=Title, filetypes=fileTypes)
            
        window.destroy()
        
    # %% create a GUI
    window = tk.Tk()
    
    #window.iconify()  # minimize to icon
    window.withdraw()  # hide it 
    
    window.after(10000, window.destroy)
    
    open_file()
    
    window.mainloop()
    
    return filename

# --- main ---

filename = get_filename()

if filename:  # check if filename was really selected
    print('selected:', filename)
else:
    print("you didn't select filename")
```

---

**EDIT:**

Reduced version which can run with parameters

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog 

def get_filename(title='Choose a file', directory='/', file_types = (('Text files', '*.txt'), ('Csv files', '*.csv'), ('All files', '*.*'))):

    window = tk.Tk()
    
    #window.iconify()  # minimize to icon
    window.withdraw()  # hide it 
    
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title=title, initialdir=directory, filetypes=file_types)
        
    window.destroy()
    
    return filename

# --- main ---

filename = get_filename(directory='/')

if filename:  # check if filename was really selected
    print('selected:', filename)
else:
    print("you didn't select filename")
```

Comment: wow!!! you are right! I only modified your solution removing the _window.destroy_ from the gui creation because it is already called from the _open_file_ function. Thank you very much!

Comment: I added version with reduced code which can run with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the solution proposed by *Furas*, the following code might represent the Python version of the *UiGetFile* Matlab function. The only drawback is the strange behaviour of the filedialog that sometimes appears in foreground and sometimes in background (using Spyder 5).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def UiGetFile(fileDialogTitle='Select the file to open', initialDirectory='/', fileTypes = (('Text files', '*.txt'), ('Csv files', '*.csv'), ('All files', '*.*'))):
    filePath = []
    fileName = []    
    window = tk.Tk()    
    #window.iconify()  # minimize to icon
    window.withdraw()  # hide it 
    
    fullname = filedialog.askopenfilename(title=fileDialogTitle, initialdir=initialDirectory, filetypes=fileTypes)        
    window.destroy()
    if fullname:
        allIndices = [i for i, val in enumerate(fullname) if val == '/']
        filePath = fullname[0 : 1+max(allIndices)]
        fileName = fullname[1+max(allIndices) : ]
                   
    return filePath, fileName


# --- main ---
fullname = UiGetFile()
print('File path: ', fullname[0])
print('File name: ', fullname[1])
```